# Bash script to detect last command runned in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, input-history

I have to make a script that print all commands used by user. So I try to make a script that will run in background and which deletes history and registers every command runned from that moment and echo it in a file. This is what I did but it doesn't work.

```
function add_new_command() {
    nr=$(history | wc -l)
    
    if [ $nr -eq 1 ]; then 
        comanda=$(history | head -n 1)
        echo $comanda > mycommands
        history -c
    fi
}

history -c
while true
do
add_new_command
done
```

Comment: __Why__ do you need to do this? It sounds like an incorrect solution to another problem.

Comment: It is a part from a project where i have 2 components client-server. And i have to send the commands to the server. But I wanted to do this little part before connecting to see how it works. Basicly, I want this script only to write in a file the commands and then with another code i will send the content of the file to the server.

Comment: Your code would not execute any commands, is that actually what you want?

Comment: I want that every command i execute after i run the script to be writen in that file, and i dont know how to do that

Comment: i dont know if it is correct to delete the content of ~/.bash_history and after some seconds to copy what is inside that file into my file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach is to use the built-in variables for controlling history.

```sh
history -c
BASH_HISTORY=mycommands
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a change and i think it gonna work now. I added next 2 lines in ~/.bashrc:

```
    shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

and now all command from more than 1 terminal are instantly copy in ~/.bash_history . so all i need to do is to copy that file.